# change the class of a div but not the span in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rollover

I have a `<div>` with a grey border that I am using as a button.

I am using jQuery to change the border color to black when I roll over it (by changing the css class on `mouseover`). In the `<div>` there is also a `<span>` with my button text.

The trouble is when I roll over the text that picks up the css class change info too and my text then has a black border.

I want to know if there is a way for javascript or jQuery to ignore the `<span>` text and treat it as if it were not there.

I just want the border color of the button to change, not add a border to my text too.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You need to reformat your post. the div and span tags arent showing

Comment: Could you give some sample code? A jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) would be really helpful.

Comment: also, post your jquery code, and your styles if you don't mind

Comment: Are you sure it isn't simply that you have a CSS rule for `div.normal span`, but not a rule for `div.rolledover span`? I.e. when you change the div's class, the CSS for the span doesn't apply anymore. If that's the case, just set your CSS to `div.normal span, div.rolledover span { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your selector when you apply the new style is wrong and includes the content of the span too.

But for all the cosmetics change of the mouse over event please use the css way :)
Lot cleaner.

```
.myClass
{
  // css of the button
}
.myClass:hover
{
  // css of the button when mouse over it.
}
```

Comment: But, as always, be aware that IE6 won't fully get it. IE6 only understands `:hover` on a `<a>` tags

Answer (score 1):

As @Jean-Philippe said, jQuery is not necessary for this, css contains all the functionality you need to change th elook of an element when you're hovering over it.

It can also be done with jQuery but I fail to see what the problem would be.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9EGSd/) demonstrates both methods, neither put a border on the internal span